# TaperMonkey dynamically clicking

Tags: javascript

How do I simulate a click on a table row which does not have a onclick attribute.  Usually when I clixk on it, a new page gets openesd. But how do I do it In my code? 
let me make my question clearer. Suppose     When I normally click on the first row.. It redirects to another page.  Now since the onclick attribute does not have a function name I am not able to figure out what exactly is being called. Now what I want to do is to simulate the click on the row. I can't change the source since its on the server, I am using inspector in chrome right now and tapermonkey to write js code.  Click() function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
var trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

var redirect = function() {
  if (this.dataset && this.dataset.target) return window.location.href = this.dataset.target;
};

for (var i = 0, ii = trs.length; i < ii; i++) {
  trs[i] && trs[i].addEventListener('click', redirect, false);
}
```

```css
tr:hover {
  background: #EEE;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr data-target="https://google.com">
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-target="https://developer.mozilla.org">
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-target="http://stackoverflow.com/">
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Suppose When I normally click on the first row.. It redirects to another page. Now since the onclick attribute does not have a function name I am not able to figure out what exactly is being called. Now what I want to do is to simulate the click on the row. I can't change the source since its on the server, I am using inspector in chrome right now and tapermonkey to write js code. Click() function is not working.